# Moving arrow to the bottom of the graph using graphviz

Tags: graphs

I was trying to use `graphviz` to crete the following graph:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=TB;
    size="8,5"
    node [shape = circle]; 0 1 2 3 4 5
    node [shape = circle];
    1 -> 2 [];
    2 -> 3 [];
    3 -> 4 [];
    4 -> 5 [];
    5 -> 1 [];
    0 -> 1 [];
    0 -> 2 [];
    0 -> 3 [];
    0 -> 4 [];
    0 -> 5 [];
   {rank=same 5; 2; 3; 4; 1; }
}
```

Output:

[image]

How can I move the edge `5->1` to the bottom? So it would be something like as following:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GraphViz isn't TeX-related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot tell you how to steer graphwiz but such things can be done easily without this tool.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={draw,thick,minimum size=1cm,circle,align=center},
cc/.style={on chain,join,circ},start chain=going right,
every join/.append style={-latex,thick},
node distance=8mm,font=\sffamily]
 \foreach \X in {1,...,5}
 {\node[cc] (\X){\X};}
 \node[above=of 3,circ] (0){0}; 
 \foreach \X in {1,...,5}
 {\draw[-latex,thick] (0) -- (\X);}
 \draw[-latex,thick] (5) to[out=-135,in=-45] (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Set the direction of an edge by adding `:n`, `:ne`, `:e`, … as the compass direction of the edge. So, replace `5 -> 1` with `5:s -> 1` as follows:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir = TB
  node [shape = circle]
  1 -> 2
  2 -> 3
  3 -> 4
  4 -> 5
  5:s -> 1
  0 -> 1
  0 -> 2
  0 -> 3
  0 -> 4
  0 -> 5
  {rank = same 1 2 3 4 5 }
}
```

[image: Graphviz dot graph]